# Celluloid resize pool

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, celluloid

I have the following program structure.

```
client = Client.new
params = client.get_params
pool = client.pool(size: params.size)

futures = params.map do |p|
    pool.future(:perform_work, p)
end

futures.map(&:value)
```

Client is Celluloid-enabled class using `include Celluloid`. This works great until I try to execute the program in a loop. I need to dynamically resize pool of workers based on number of parameters I receive from external data-feed.

```
client = Client.new
pool = client.pool(size: 1)

loop do
   params = client.get_params

   ....
   **? pool.resize(size: params.size) ?**
   ....

   futures = params.map do |p|
      pool.future(:perform_work, p)
   end

   futures.map(&:value)
   sleep 1
end
```

I tried include pool creation into the loop with subsequent `pool.terminate` but it's spamming threads and leads to actor crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting pool.size explicitly did the trick it seems

```
client = Client.new
pool = client.pool(size: 1)

loop do
   params = client.get_params
   pool.size = params.size

   futures = params.map do |p|
      pool.future(:perform_work, p)
   end

   futures.map(&:value)
   sleep 1
end
```